# Right click disable not working for scroll button click, It shows alert but opens in new tab

Tags: javascript, dom-events, mouseevent, contextmenu

I am disabling Right click for my website, but when I use mouse and click the scroll button, It shows alert and then after clicking on OK it opens in new Tab. How can I disable that?.
Below is my  Javascript code. Please help me out.

```
// Right Click Disable Functions starts here

function clickIE()
{
    if (document.all) 
    {
        alert("Right click is disabled for Security Reasons.");
        return false;
    }
 }

function clickNS(e) 
{  
    if(document.layers||(document.getElementById&&!document.all)) 
    {
        if (e.which==2||e.which==3)
        {
            alert("Right click is disabled for Security Reasons.");
            return false;
        }
    }    
}

if (document.layers)
{
    document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN);
    document.onmousedown=clickNS;
}
else
{
    document.onmouseup=clickNS;document.oncontextmenu=clickIE;
}
    document.oncontextmenu=new Function("return false")

// Right Click Disable Functions Ends here
```

Comment: can you please add whole code...I think this code is perfect...

Comment: i have added the complete code now. It goes inside if , But when i click ok on that alert box. It opens in new tab @ParthRaval

Comment: This is working....I don't see any bug in the code...

Comment: I am not able to see where you have added your code to open new Tab.

Answer (score 0):

The **mouseup** event fired after **mousedown** event.
what you need is to preventing **mousedown** event (for right and middle click). so
You just have to use **document.onmousedown** insted of **document.onmouseup**.